# How can I make Excel handle fractions like Quickbooks?

Tags: quickbooks, spreadsheet

When you have a fraction in Excel like 1.085 rounded to two decimals = 1.09.
In Excel if you add a series of these fractions with displayed two decimals of precision you are really adding 1.085 and not 1.09.  The problem is that Quickbooks is using 1.09.  That means calculations in Quickbooks and Excel accumulate differences.

Mathematically Excel is correct.  But for accounting purposes I need to do what Quickbooks does.

The question - how do I get Excel to ACTUALLY round to two decimals of precision and use that number in the subsequent calculations like Quickbooks does?

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @Yishai Certainly, but we allow questions asking about software for personal finance.  So, it's fine, but SU would be a better site for it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the round function. If the value of 1.085 is in cell A1

```
=ROUND(A1,2)
```

The 2 tells Excel how many digits to the right of the decimal point to keep. You can also use zero or a negative number.

Excel has other functions to control rounding including ROUNDUP() , ROUNDDOWN(), and MROUND()